# How can we execute a shell command from a chrome extension; is there a provided way?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

How can we execute a (shell or bash) command from a chrome extension; is there a provided way in the Chrome API?

Answer (score 5):

No. Such a capability would be very scary. You might be interested in the [Native Messaging API](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/10/connecting-chrome-apps-and-extensions.html), but you'll need to distribute a native application installer that typically requires administrator privileges. [Your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223382/can-we-retrieve-our-machine-serial-number-in-our-chrome-extension) suggests that that approach won't work for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for this answer it clarified it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way, provided you have a local server running. The local server can execute the command. Call the endpoint with fetch. Here an example:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: "Open in Safari",
        contexts: ["all"],
        onclick: info => {
            const u = 'http://localhost:3012/to-safari?url=info.pageUrl;
            fetch(u).then(result => console.info(result)).catch(err => console.error(err));
        }
    });
```

I made this to open the current url (in Chrome) in Safari. Of course your server can execute any command.

BTW no special permissions in manifest are necessary.