# Can we retrieve our machine serial number in our chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Can we retrieve our machine serial number in our chrome extension?

For example I can get the serial number in windows by executing following command in the shell

> wmic bios get serialnumber

How can I fetch this serial number in my chrome extension?

Comment: What is the purpose of this retrieval? I can't see any reason to validate the windows key for an extension?

Answer (score 2):

No. Chrome extensions are designed to protect user privacy to the greatest practical extent, and one component of user privacy is controlling the ability of code to "fingerprint" the user. Read the [EFF's discussion of fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) for more.

I didn't mark your question as a duplicate, but the same answer applies to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554299/how-do-you-get-the-device-name-or-hostname-from-a-chrome-extension).

Answer (score 0):

If your extension is force-installed by way of enterprise policy you can get the device serial number by using the `chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes` endpoint: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/enterprise_deviceAttributes/#method-getDeviceSerialNumber